# Match a character the same amount of times that a previous character has been matched

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need for a way to interpret `x ^ y` (I am aware that there are such solutions available, but this is challenging myself to go "library-free"). I thought about using a RegExp, as such:

```
(\(*\w+\)*|\(*Math.pow\(\w+,\w+\)\)*=*)+\s*\^\s*(\(*\w\)*)+\)*
```

(http://regexr.com/3b0dl) and a replace string `"Math.pow($1,$2)"`.

Now, this works for all cases I've tested thus far, save for the following:

## 1 - Paren surrounding expression

```
(2 ^ (5))
```

Which replaces this as thus:

```
Math.pow((2,(5)))
```

Which evaluates `(2,(5)`. Is there any way I can fix the RegExp so that it matches the `)` for as many times as it matched the `(` in the second catch group?

## 2 - Multiple iteration

```
(2 ^ 3) ^ 5
```

Is replaced with

```
Math.pow((2,3)) ^ 5
```

which leaves an unevaluated `^`. I figure that this may be done by a `while(input.match("^"){...}` sort thing, I want to know that if this is possible via RegExp.

---

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You cannot do it with regex in JavaScript.

Comment: @stribizhev Oh fine. Why not?

Comment: It has no possessive quantifiers, nor balancing constructs, nor subroutines. Thus, you should write a separate method to parse the input string.

Comment: @stribizhev what do you suggest, generally? I have little experience with such routines.

Comment: You can check this [Checking for balanced brackets in JavaScript](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/checking-for-balanced-brackets-in-javascript) post for sample code.

Comment: one simple way: just match with and without parens in two lines instead of one. yeah it's more work, but you get to use simple readable regexps for both steps instead of something scary or a user-land routine. in a long rx, you can code for 0, 1, and 2 paren wraps...